# Can you use the present progressive as a sort of future tense?

Tags: futuro, gerundio

In English, I can use “to be”, a gerund, and either a time or “when” to mean something in the future. For example, I can say

> When are you going?

and mean

> When will you be going?/When will you go?

or

> The band is playing tomorrow.

and mean

> The band will be playing tomorrow./The band will play tomorrow.

Does this structure work in Spanish?

**Unlike the other question, this is asking *if* the thing is valid. The other is asking something different.**

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the "present progressive" in Spanish (*estar* + gerund) to indicate future, but not as liberally as in English.

Most commonly Spanish uses a periphrastic future with the verb *ir* + *a* + infinitive; in some cases and especially in formal or literary language, it uses the "proper" synthetic future tense; in others it employs the present tense, including both the simple present and the present progressive or continuous.

The progressive, when used to show the future, tends to suggest **planning**:

> *Me estoy yendo de vacaciones en un mes.*
>   "I'm going on holidays in a month."

In other cases the progressive-as-future shows **immediacy**:

> *Estoy yendo a buscarla a su casa.*
>   "I'm going to fetch her at home."

meaning you're just about to leave, although that's again ambiguous (it could be that you're actually going as you speak).

You **cannot** use the progressive as future for undefined or hypothetical future events; that is, you cannot say something like

> ❌ *Un día de estos me estoy comprando una gran mansión.*
>   "One of these days I'm getting a big mansion."

In such cases you need to use one of the other alternative ways to express future.

Comment: Why is the start of the example “Me estoy yendo”?

Comment: *Me estoy yendo* = *Estoy yéndome*. The expression goes *ir**se** de vacaciones*, with pronominal *irse* instead of plain *ir*. The pronoun *me* can move around, as you see.

Comment: Just as it happens in *[Te vas a cansar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31186/14627)*.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's consider your example sentences:

- When are you going?

  In principle you *could* use the present continuous *¿Cuándo estás saliendo [de la ciudad]?* but it's more usual to say **Cuándo vas a salir?** or **A qué hora sales?**.
- The band is playing tomorrow.

  Here, **La banda está tocando mañana** works pretty well (in addition to *La banda va a tocar mañana / La banda toca mañana*).  The difference is subtle.  "La banda está tocando mañana" covers a broader time period than the non-continuous versions, in that we are currently (now) contemplating the details of tomorrow's plan.  In other words, "La banda está tocando mañana" has the feel of something like *The current plan is for the band to play tomorrow.*

The future continuous is more common than the present continuous.  Examples of the future continuous used this way:

- ¿**Estarás ocupando** mi taladro el fin de semana?  Mi hermana lo quiere usar un día para poner un estante.

  Comparing this with the vanilla form (*Vas a ocupar mi taladro el fin de semana?*): "Estarás ocupando" is a little more vague, and therefore a little softer and less confrontational.
- **Estaré haciendo** la compra de la semana [weekly grocery shopping] pasado mañana.  ¿Nos queda suficiente pan para hoy y mañana?

Note 1: *Ir* is an exception.  Continuous forms of *ir* are unusual.  The Spanish learner is recommended to avoid it.

Note 2: There is another way of creating a continuous feel, and it is very idiomatic (natural sounding):

- Voy preparando mi terrenito para sembrar la lechuga.

  This means: *I'm preparing the soil to plan lettuce*, or *I'm in the process of preparing the soil etc.*

It can also be put into the future, similar to what we saw above with the standard future continuous:

- ¿Irás haciendo depósitos mensuales en mi cuenta para pagar el préstamo?