# How does "Te vas a cansar" mean "You're going to get tired"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, reflexivos, verbo-pronominal, subida-de-clíticos

Why does "Te vas a cansar" mean "You're going to get tired"? *Irse* means to leave, to go, to die, to go away and to forget. There is no translation which means "to become something" for instance, "to become tired".

Comment: I'm not really sure what your doubt is. You're saying that "irse" means "to go" but it surprises you that "irse a" translates as "going to"?

Comment: irse is to leave or go way, not to go. Me voy ahora. I'm leaving now.

Comment: The reflexive verb of "ir" means leave. "Ir" itself means "to go". So "Voy ahora" (following your example) I'm going now. (I'm on my way). Or as you said "me voy ahora" means I'm leaving now. ir = go whereas irse = leave

Comment: @Charlie We always tell people not to trust literal translations of periphrases such as the "be going to" structure in English. What "ir a" + infinitive means is not obvious, especially when complicated by a pronominal verb.

Comment: One thing that may help is to try to stop thinking of Spanish and English as being equivalent; they're not.  There is no English word or phrase that *exactly means* Spanish word or phrase XYZ; instead there is an English word or phrase (usually) that can be translated (with some degree of precision) to/from the Spanish word or phrase XYZ.  Thinking of languages as completely separate entities that can be approximately translated one to the other is helpful when attempting to learn a new language.  It prevents many errors like this one, and also opens to the door to thinking in the new language

Answer (score 16):

*Te vas a cansar* or, alternatively, *Vas a cansarte*, illustrates two grammatical concepts:

1. Pronominal verbs, like *cansarse*, which means "to get tired, to become tired"; contrast this with plain *cansar* which means "to tire, to make somebody tired". Pronominal verbs are those which use a "reflexive" pronoun even though they're not reflexive (like *cansarse*, *caerse*, *reírse*, etc.).
2. The use of the verb *ir* plus a verbal infinitive to show future, as in *vas a cansarte*. This is similar to English *to be going to*. It's a very common structure because the "proper" future tense is used less and less in spoken Spanish.

*Vas a* + infinitive therefore means "You're going to" + whatever. And for *cansarse*, you have to employ a pronoun that refers back to the subject, in this case the second person singular pronoun *te*. Thus, *vas a cansarte* = "you're going to get tired". There are additional rules that say that, in this kind of structure, you can move the pronoun in certain ways; in particular, you can move it away from the back of the infinitive (*vas a cansar**te***) and place it before the main verb (***te*** vas a cansar). The pronoun is still bound to *cansar*, though.

[image: ir a + infinitive]

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but did @[pablodf76](/users/14627) generate [the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWLug.png) on the fly?

Comment: @Lucas The diagram was made with a vector editor (Inkscape), exported as a PNG file and then uploaded normally into the answer box. SE just uses imgur.com to store images.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the verb *cansarse* means "to get/become tired." The *te* is a part of *cansarse* and not a part of *irse.* Context tells you which verb the *te* corresponds to.

Equivalently, you could say *Vas a cansarte.*

Answer (score 3):

This phrase translates literally to "You're going to tire", but that's not idiomatic in English. So instead, it's translated to "You're going to get tired".

There are small differences in languages like this, even for simple, basic phrases. For instance "Tengo sed" means literally "I have thirst"-- but nobody talks this way in English. English speakers say instead, "I am thirsty", meaning the exact same thing, so the phrase is translated to that, instead of literally.

Comment: I think the OP was puzzled by _irse_ not by _cansar_

Comment: @mdewey could be, but OP harps more on "to become" part, which the "get" in English means.

Comment: This answer is great because that it focuses on the difficulty (truthfully the impossibility) of translating idioms perfectly between two languages word-for-word.  It also shows why attempting to learn one language via translation to and from another language is fraught with difficulty: because no two languages are equivalent to each other; they can at best be translated one to the other, and that *imperfectly*.

Comment: "Cansarse" can be translated in a way that retains the reflexive flavor: *To tire oneself (out)*, e.g. *You're going to tire yourself out.*

Comment: @aparente001At least, to my American ears, *to wear out* sounds more idiomatic, and while it is also reflexive, it doesn't preserve the exact verb.