# Why are some verbs reflexive and non-reflexive?

Tags: gramática

I have been studying Spanish for a while. I still have basic questions , one of which is:

Why do some verbs sometimes use "se" in the infinitive and sometimes not?

Example: ir de marcha/irse de marcha.
Comer/comerse
Recordar/recordarse
There are loads.
I understand reflexive verbs,  e.g. lavarse/afeitarse mean to wash oneself/shave etc. I don't have a problem with those.
Is the "se" optional?
I know in Hiberno-English(Ireland) we often say things like , I like to take off with myself on holiday, or I like to sit myself down with a good book. This sounds conversational and natural. Is it similar?
Or has it something to do with Direct and Indirect Object pronouns and duplication which I read  about in a previous post?
I am sorry ,therefore if I am duplicating a question!

Comment: I think most of what you're asking is covered by [this canonical question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there). Please check and see if it does answer your question.

Comment: (especially, check the "sympathetic dative" and "aspectual dative" sections).

Comment: You may also gain by reviewing some of the posts here about pronominal verbs which the anglophone learner is often taught are reflexive. The relevant tag here is [tag:verbo-pronominal]

Comment: The use if _ir/irse_ has been discussed https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31184/how-does-te-vas-a-cansar-mean-youre-going-to-get-tired as that is the example you mention but really most of the tagged questions are worth a read.

Comment: Sometimes, it's a semantic difference.  *Ir* is like the English *to go*.  *Irse* is more like *to go away*.